# Sharepoint 2013 search result Security trimminng

Tags: search, sharepoint-2013, security-trimming

I found that security trimming in search result behavior differently in sharepoint 2013 with 2010, In 2010, search result automatically trimmed if current user has no permission to read the document, while in 2013, all the result showed up even if user has no privilege for view, and when click on the document, sharepoint redirect you to a page said "Access Denied".

I want to know how to make 2013 behavior the same as 2010 in security trimming, any ideas about this? thank you smart guys in advance, any idea will be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: That's odd, it shouldn't show results if user does not have access to it. Maybe you have sort of security trimming customization?

Comment: @Yevgeniy, Thanks a lot for your reply, but I have done no customization sort of security trimming, Do you know the behavior in 2013 should security trimming automatically or not? If that, I'll try more enviroment to ensure that this is not an enviromental issue.

Comment: It should automatically apply security trimming to sharepoint content. If you do crawl of some other location (custom database for example) you need to provide security manually though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes effectively the results show up even if the user hasn't access but if you try to access the document you will be informed that you haven't access.
Restart a full Crawl on your searched content and the result will change to represent what the user has access at the crawling time. ACL(s) will be recalculated.